# Lua - Error Attempt to perform arithmetic on field '?' -- This occurs at the end of the for loop

Tags: lua

I'm developing a program for the Ti-nspire CX CAS calculator and at the time of execution it indicates an error on line 52, this is presented at the end of the for loop in the "area" function.
Sorry for my English.

```
local coX = {0,2,2,0}
local coY = {0,0,2,0}
local xmax = 2
local ymax = 2

-- Matriz de coordenadas para función "on.paint(gc)"
function conCoor(x,y)
    local nx = x
    for i=1, #x do
        table.insert(nx,i*2,y[i])       
    end
    return nx
end

-- Valor absoluto
function math.abs(valor)
    if valor < 0 then
        valor = valor*(-1)
    end
    return valor
end

-- Inercia del polígono respecto el eje X
function inerciex(x,y)
    local E = 0
    local z =0
    for i = 1, #x-1 do
        E = (x[i+1]-x[i])*(y[i+1]+y[i])*((y[i+1])^2+(y[i])^2)
        z = E + z
    end
    return math.abs(z/12)
end

-- Inercia del polígono respecto el eje Y
function inerciey(x,y)
    local E = 0
    local z =0
    for i = 1, #x-1 do
        E = (y[i+1]-y[i])*(x[i+1]+x[i])*((x[i+1])^2+(x[i])^2)
        z = E + z
    end
    return math.abs(z/12)
end

-- Área del poligono
function area(x,y)
    local A = 0
    local z = 0
    for i = 1, #x-1 do
        A = (y[i]*x[i+1]-x[i]*y[i+1])
        z = A + z
    end -- Line 52, the line in question
    return math.abs(z/2)
end

-- Centro de masa del polígono (eje x)
function centroix(x,y)
    local Ac = area(x,y)
    local z = 0
    local cx = 0
    for i = 1, #x-1 do
        cx = (x[i]+x[i+1])*(x[i]*y[i+1]-x[i+1]*y[i])
        z = cx + z
    end
    return z/(6*Ac)
end

-- Centro de masa del polígono (eje y)
function centroiy(x,y)
    local Ac = area(x,y)
    local z = 0
    local cx = 0
    for i = 1, #x-1 do
        cx = (y[i]+y[i+1])*(x[i]*y[i+1]-x[i+1]*y[i])
        z = cx + z
    end
    return z/(6*Ac)
end

-- Escala de figura
function escala(xmax,ymax)
    local sc = 0
    if xmax > ymax then
        sc = 81/xmax
    else
        sc = 81/ymax
    end
    return math.floor(sc)
end

-- Coordenadas del origen en pantalla
function oriDispX(x,y,xmax,ymax)
    return math.floor(212 + (-1)*centroix(x,y)*escala(xmax,ymax))
end

function oriDispY(x,y,xmax,ymax)
    return math.floor(105 + (-1)*centroiy(x,y)*escala(xmax,ymax))
end

-- Cambio de coordenadas real
function coorCamb(x,y,xmax,ymax)
    -- Escalado de coordenadas
    local escx = x
    local escy = y
    local orix = oriDispX(escx,escy,xmax,ymax)
    local oriy = oriDispY(escx,escy,xmax,ymax)
    for i = 1, #escx do
        escx[i] = math.floor(escx[i]*escala(xmax,ymax))
        escy[i] = math.floor(escy[i]*escala(xmax,ymax))
    end
    -- Cambio de coordenadas
    for i = 1, #escx do
        escx[i] = escx[i] + orix
        escy[i] = escy[i] + oriy
    end
    return conCoor(escx,escy)
end

function on.paint(gc)
    local ox = oriDispX(coX,coY,xmax,ymax)
    local oy = oriDispY(coX,coY,xmax,ymax)
    local c = coorCamb(coX,coY,xmax,ymax)
    gc:drawPolyLine(c)
    gc:drawLine(ox-3,oy,ox+3,oy)
    gc:drawLine(ox,oy-3,ox,oy+3)
    gc:fillArc(ox-1,oy-1,2,2,0,360)
    gc:fillArc(212-1,105-1,2,2,0,360)
    gc:drawString(tostring(area(coX,coY)),10,10)
    platform.window:invalidate()
end
```

More specifically, the error occurs here:

```
function area(x,y)
    local A = 0
    local z = 0
    for i = 1, #x-1 do
        A = (y[i]*x[i+1]-x[i]*y[i+1])
        z = A + z
    end -- Line 52, the line in question
    return math.abs(z/2)
end
```

Comment: Probably, input arguments passed to `area()` are wrong.

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: @tonypdmtr - Error message is in the title

Comment: How are you calling the code? I agree with @EgorSkriptunoff; the inputs are probably incorrect, but we won't know what to look for unless you tell us how it progresses.

Answer (score 1):

Your code assumes both X and Y arrays are of equal size (because you use i index for both X and Y array), or at least Y never smaller than X. i index, however, runs from 1 to the size of X array which will be invalid for Y array of smaller size.

So, if the Y array is smaller than the X array, you get that error.  And, here's the proof:

```
function area(x,y)
  local A = 0
  local z = 0
  for i = 1, #x-1 do
    A = (y[i]*x[i+1]-x[i]*y[i+1])
    z = A + z
  end
  return math.abs(z/2)
end

print(area({1,2,3},{4,5,6})) -- OK
print(area({1,2,3},{4,5})) -- ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to initialize the variables and tables at the beginning of the whole script and then call the new values ​​using "var.recall" inside the on.paint function.